# Unable to renew lets encrypt using certbot

Tags: centos, centos6, python, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm running centos 6, I recently tried installing python 3, might have messed something up related to python

if I do

`python2 /usr/local/bin/certbot-auto renew`

I get

```
file "/usr/local/bin/certbot-auto", line 20 if [ -z "$HOME" ]; then ^ 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I do

`/usr/local/bin/certbot-auto renew`

I get

```
import ssl File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 146, in <module> 
import base64        # for DER-to-PEM translation File 
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/base64.py", line 11, in <module> import binascii 
ImportError: No module named binascii WARNING: unable to check for 
updates. Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 16, in 
<module> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/version.py", line 140, 
in cmp compare = cmp(self.version, other.version) AttributeError: 
StrictVersion instance has no attribute 'version' root@~$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certbot was trying to run using python 2.6 which broken, I read the certbot bash script and saw that it can run using python 3 as well, so I ran it using python 3 like this

`USE_PYTHON_3=1 ./usr/local/bin/certbot-auto renew`

Issue solved